# Can't load Activity on orientation change

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, screen-orientation

I was able to load new Activity on button click:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, LandscapeActivity.class));

        }
```

But can do it when orientation changed. I've put this into initial layout *(activity_main)*:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
```

And this into initial activity *(MainActivity)* (tried commented string also):

```
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
    {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_landscape);
        //startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, LandscapeActivity.class));
    }
```

`onConfigurationChanged` just not being called as logs show. Screen is rotating.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the landscape layout manually, you want to instead define a layout file under `res/layout-land`. See https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html#create-layouts

Comment: I just put it there - nothing changed.

Comment: Did you give it the same name as the one under res/layout?

Comment: Have a read through https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#RetainingAnObject

Comment: Basically remove "orientation" from your configChanges value. You only need that if you want to handle config changes yourself. In this case you just need a different layout, which the system will handle for you provided that you have a layout file with the same name under `-land` folder

Comment: What is the name of the two layout files you have?

Comment: **"activity_main.xml"** and **"activity_landscape.xml"** , or **".MainActivity"** and **".LandscapeActivity"** in manifest.

Comment: Call them both activity_main.xml but put them in layout and layout-land. In both files it should refer to .MainActivity

Comment: I tried - only main activity rotates, no other appear.

Comment: I attached my project to the end of question.

Answer (score 0):

This method seems to work for only 14+ sdk versions, so if your sdk version is lower than that it probably won't work.

possible solution: is to change your targetSDK version to 14 or more.

Comment: My min is set to 20.

Comment: I attached my project to the end of question.